# Change first child ::before style when .active

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I have a menu that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/beX6i.png

The little triangle is made using ::before. I need to make it change into the color of the hover when the first child of the submenu is active (has .active class that is added from js automatically)

What should the selector look like? something like .submenu a:first-child.active?

CSS:

```
.submenu{

        z-index:10;
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        background:#2b2b2b;         
    }


    .submenu a{

        font-family:'Roboto Slab';
        display:block;
        color:white;
        background:transparent;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        line-height:58px;
        padding-left:8px;
        padding-right:8px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    .submenu a:hover{
        color:#fe4817;
        display:block;
        background-color:#3A3939;
    }

    .submenu a.active{
        color:#fe4817;
        background-color:#3A3939;
    }


    .submenu a:first-child:before,
    .submenu a:first-child::before{
        position:absolute;
        top:-8px;
        left:0;
        content:' ';
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        border-right: 15px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #2b2b2b;
    }

    .submenu a:first-child:hover:before,
    .submenu a:first-child:hover::before{
        border-bottom: 15px solid #3A3939;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the html markup? Or even better, a fiddle to show your problem?

Comment: Basically I don't know how to select the ::before triangle when the first child of the submenu (submenu a:first-child) has the .active class

Comment: You seem to have an idea of how this should be done (from your post)...have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to understand your question. But I think

```
.submenu a:first-of-type.active:before {
    border-bottom-color:#3a3939;
}
```

should do the job. `:first-of-type` might be better than `:first-child` in this case since `:first-child` could either be a heading or something alike while `:first-of-type` only selects the first anchor. See [Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for further information.

If that doesn't work and you can provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) I'll take another look at your problem.

Comment: My concern here is that (without knowing the HTML), every anchor tag will be `first` since it would, normally, be the only child of an `li`. I would normally expect to see this triangle as an `li:first-child:before` not on an anchor...but +1 anyway.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly, that selector was just what I needed :) Sorry for the lack of a fiddle, it's really hard to make one considering all the php, js stuff going on. Anyways, thanks!